# Cannot find certain words in context, missing reference, brain about to explode?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to learn C#/Silverlight/Windows Phone 7. What's going on here: When I try to use examples straight off of MS's MSDN site, and I get all kinds of errors:

For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Device.Location;
using Microsoft.Phone.Reactive;

  private void registerPhone(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
```

It tells me

1) `The name 'Encoding' does not exist in this context`

2) `System.Net.WebRequest does not contain a definition for GetStreamRequest and no extension method GetRequestStream accepting a first argument of type System.Net.WebRequest could be found (are you missing a using directive... etc`

3) a similar message for ContentLength

4) a similar message for GetResponse

I have no idea what libraries I need to be "using" and even when I think I'm "using" the right ones, it gives me errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what other platform or language are you comparing C# with? That is, where did you have your previous experience that a novice **does** have an idea what libraries to use?

Comment: Perhaps the main source of your confusion is that you are reading the wrong part of the MSDN library. That code is clearly not applicable to Windows Phone 7. You should be here:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838158(v=VS.95).aspx and remember that Windows Phone 7 is essentially Silverlight 3 not 4.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, I've been spoiled by Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse when developing for Android

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can organize "usings" by right-clicking and selecting "Organize Usings". You can also assign a hotkey to this option. Besides that, when you need to use a class that is not in "usings" yet, you can just write it's name, and then hit `Ctrl+.` (control-dot) and select the first item in the menu. The Visual Studio will figure out what namespace the class is in, and automatically add it to the "usings". Any other confusions I can help you with?

Comment: Also, as a side note: please try to refrain from overly emotional negative comments. This upsets a lot of people (myself included) and makes you sound immature and unprofessional. Just the fact that you cannot deal with a new technology with the same ease you could with a familiar one, does not mean that the technology itself is in some sense inferior.

Comment: Thanks. I will try these out and as I learn my way around this new environment. Your last point is true, and I agree. I reread my question today and came to similar conclusions. Thanks for taking a chance on me despite the fact that my question was so emotionally charged :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Encoding` class resides in the `System.Text` namespace. You have to add that to the "usings".

As far as for the other messages, this has to do with the limitations of Silverlight. The MSDN samples, I presume, were taken from the "big" version of .NET Framework, weren't they?

In Silverlight, you see, some things are not allowed in order to prevent undesirable application behavior (such as blocking calls), and some things are not supported due to resources limitation.

In particular, `ContentLength` is one of the latter. The library will determine the content length based on the actual amount of data you write into the request. Just remove that line, you'll be ok.

But `GetResponseStream()` is actually one of the former. It has to do with the fact that this operation implies actually opening network connection, which may take a while. And since blocking calls are not allowed in Silverlight, the `GetResponseStream()` method also has to go.

Instead, you're supposed to use the so-called "asynchronous pattern" - that is, the pair of methods `BeginGetResponseStream`/`EndGetResponseStream`. You do it by calling the `Begin` method and providing a callback that will be called once the operation is complete. Then, inside that callback, you use the `End` method to get the result of the operation. Like so:

```
            request.BeginGetRequestStream( ar =>
            {
                var dataStream = request.EndGetRequestStream( ar );

                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write( byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length );
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();

                // and so on...

            }, null );
```

Same goes for the `GetResponse` method.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, the best thing to do is to read the documentation.

For instance, a quick look at MSDN tells me that `Encoding` is a part of `System.Text` (docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)).

Second, it would seem that the sample code that you copy/pasted onto your project was not for Windows Phone. If you look at the docs for Windows Phone's `WebRequest`, you'll notice that synchronous operations are not supported on the phone. You have to use asynchronous [`WebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead.

By the way, when checking out MSDN documentation, make sure you're reading the Silverlight version (you can choose near the top of the page, under the article's title) and if you're working with Windows Phone, look for the blue phone icon for supported methods.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to resolve these errors is:

- right click on the offending word - e.g. Encoding - it should be underlined 'red' or 'blue' in Visual Studio
- on the context menu there is an option Resolve
- this option will contain submenus offering you ways to resolve it - either by including "using System.Text" or by using "System.Text.Encoding"

Hope that helps.

Hope you enjoy playing with the new tools - I've gone the other way recently and it just takes a little time to get used to the different way different tools work - give it time and try to enjoy it!